# Bat file with dual command set

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file with **two sets of commands**:

### First Set:

```
@echo off
set varip=10.0.80.40
REM WRITE YOUR COMPUTER IP ABOVE
set vardefaultgway=10.0.80.1
set varsubnetmask=255.255.255.192
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static %varip% %varsubnetmask% %vardefaultgway%
```

### Second Set:

```
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=dhcp
```

So now I want a batch file of the following format.

### Resultant Set

```
@echo off
REM BOOLEAN_VALUE
REM //some code here that reads the BOOLEAN_VALUE and goes to command-set-1 or command-set-2 depending on the result
:1
set varip=10.0.80.40
REM WRITE YOUR COMPUTER IP ABOVE
set vardefaultgway=10.0.80.1
set varsubnetmask=255.255.255.192
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static %varip% %varsubnetmask% %vardefaultgway%
REM //some code to change the BOOLEAN_VALUE i.e. a toggler
exit
:2
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=dhcp
REM //some code to change the BOOLEAN_VALUE i.e. a toggler
exit
```

> Basically, I need a batch file that has a BOOLEAN_VALUE just as a
>   placeholder. The batch file needs to perform these two functions:
>   
>       1. The batch file needs to read itself for the value in the
>   second line and 4th character.
>   
>     2.Upon the completion of any set of commands, the batch file must then change the value in its placeholder(i.e. BOOLEAN_VALUE) before exit.

I hope I've made myself clear. Can this be done guys?

Comment: Are you planning on asking the user for input?

Comment: @Squashman: No user input. That'd be too easy. Its just a matter of set/p I just want a click-and-run toggle file.

Comment: You contradicted yourself.  You basically said you are going to use `SET /P` which is what you use for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution does *exactly what you requested* in the question:

```
@echo off
REM Y
REM This is the code that reads the BOOLEAN_VALUE and goes to command-set-1 or command-set-2 depending on the result
for /F "usebackq skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in ("%~F0") do set "BOOLEAN_VALUE=%%a" & goto continue
:continue
ECHO BOOLEAN_VALUE=%BOOLEAN_VALUE%
IF %BOOLEAN_VALUE% EQU Y GOTO 2
:1
set varip=10.0.80.40
REM WRITE YOUR COMPUTER IP ABOVE
set vardefaultgway=10.0.80.1
set varsubnetmask=255.255.255.192
netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static %varip% %varsubnetmask% %vardefaultgway%
GOTO UPDATE_BOOLEAN_VALUE
:2
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Ethernet" source=dhcp
:UPDATE_BOOLEAN_VALUE
REM The code to change the BOOLEAN_VALUE i.e. a toggler
if %BOOLEAN_VALUE% equ Y (set "BOOLEAN_VALUE=N") else set "BOOLEAN_VALUE=Y"
(
echo @echo off
echo REM %BOOLEAN_VALUE%
for /F "usebackq skip=2 delims=" %%a in ("%~F0") do echo %%a
) > _new_.bat
move /Y _new_.bat "%~F0" > NUL
echo BOOLEAN_VALUE updated
exit
```

Note that you can not insert blank lines; a modification is needed in order to manage blank lines in the program.

Comment: +1 Not only did you do **exactly** as asked but I really liked your implementation. For the lack of a better word, its clean code. For a second there, I thought my question was too unclear but damn son did you dispel those thoughts! Would +2 if I could :D

Comment: That said, this is not the way I would implemented this. Instead of a "boolean variable" (that _not_ exist in Batch) I would used a numeric one with values 0 or 1 that was initialized in the second line this way: `set /A FlipFlop=!0`. The `!0` arithmetic expression gives `1`, and `!1` gives `0`, so the separate "toggler" code is not needed. The selection code becomes `goto %FlipFlop%` and update code becomes: `echo set /A FlipFlop=!%FlipFlop%`. This method also allows to use _more than 2 sections_ (up to 9 max) using "mod" `%` operator: `set /A value=(N+1)%%M`, so `value` is in `0..M-1` range.

Comment: while that's a nice optimal-first approach, I prefer this for my usecase because I can simply change Y and N to string "GHAR" and "LABA", and simply echoing them, effectively eliminating the need to substitute while displaying where the configuration would be applied. But sure, I'll try your other version too when the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Boolean_value` to either *nothing* using

```
set "Boolean_value="
```

or some value - any value you like, eg

```
set "Boolean_value=Y"
```

Then use

```
if defined Boolean_value (doonething) else (doanotherthing)
```

if that's what you want...

Comment: It seems you've not read the question properly. The format I require is clearly given in the resultant mock/sample. [I've already received an acceptable answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42826140/5040900).

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
(<%~f0:bool set /p bool=) 2>nul 
set /a bool=1-bool
>%~f0:bool echo %bool%

if %bool%==1 goto :1
echo do one thing
goto :eof
:1
echo do other thing
```

Line 2 gets data from alternate data stream (technically a secondary file bound to the primary file, but it's not a file on it's own)
line 3 toggles between `0` and `1`
line 4 writes the toggled value back to the alternate data stream